# Python, Pandas : I want to use pandas with a user login form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have make a form with tKinter that has 2 Entries (username, password)

I also have a csv file that contains my user info

I am importing the file like so:

```
admin_df = pd.read_csv('csv/admins.csv')
```

I want to get the username and password that the user is going to give me and check if they are in my dataframe

I figured out that I can check for the username like so:

```
if(df.admin_df[df.admin_df['username'].str.contains(username)].empty)
```

But I am having trouble with the password
I don't want to check the whole dataframe for the given password, I want to get the outcome from when I "found" the username and check if the given password is the same as I have in the dataframe

I have tried some things:

where "username" is the given username and "password" is the given password

```
1) user_df[df.user_df['username'].str.contains(username)]['password'].str.match(password)

2) user_df[df.user_df['username'].str.contains(username)]['password'].to_string == "password"

1) user_df[df.user_df['username'].str.contains(username)]['password'].str.match(password).any()
```

Problems (as I understand them):
1)It is not really a boolean
2)It is not really a string
3)It did not work (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fixes. This line will get you the row with only username and password values for the username specified. Watch out that `str.contains()` also accepts subset of the string and you don't want that.

```
user_info = admin_df[['username', 'password']][admin_df['username'] == username]
```

Then you can check if the password matches using this:

```
user_password = user_info.password.values[0]
if password == user_password:
    ....
```

You can now tweak it to your usage with conditions to handle if the user exist or not and so on.

Comment: I did that, but when I try to use it in an if statement, I have this Error: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" 
Although, when I print (admin_info.password == "HC1#2M8gqY") I get True.

Comment: @MrWobbles Edited. Just used values to get the actual value. It should work now.